# What is the reason behind error h14 "No web processes running" and Application error?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, web-deployment, heroku-cli

I made [this](https://github.com/Igaurav31/weatherForecast-Project) project and deployed it on Heroku successfully and it was working, I checked it again two months and it was working properly, but today when I tried to open the [website link](https://limitless-shelf-83830.herokuapp.com/) it says Application error.

Logs are as follows:

```
2022-12-06T08:17:30.897980+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=limitless-shelf-83830.herokuapp.com request_id=d0c862ec-c21d-4e94-94e5-f6fed3d71af6 fwd="103.141.116.193" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-12-06T08:17:31.345120+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=limitless-shelf-83830.herokuapp.com request_id=a98c5850-0aa3-413d-94d9-4480a218ec3d fwd="103.141.116.193" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Is this issue from my side or heroku servers are down? What is the cause of this error and what are possible solutions?

I tried running

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

but it had no use.

**Edit: I found the issue, Heroku has stopped offering free plans from 28th Nov 2022, and I deployed it free server.**

Comment: "I tried running `heroku ps:scale web=1`"—well, that should make your app run one web process. What does "it had no use" mean? What was the output of that command? Are you sure you're scaling the right app on Heroku?

Comment: And if you were using free dynos, have you switched to eco dynos? Free dynos were removed from Heroku's offering about a week ago.

Comment: I had no clue what ps:scale web =1, it was solution of similar problem so I tried and I got the solution, I was using free dynos. Thank you.

Comment: probably worth deleting this question, as heroku/salesforce sent out a ton of notice about this change, and future visitors aren't even going to be able to run into this =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, Heroku no longer provides free dyno plans.

Although if you have previously deployed apps, you can still access them after subscribing to one of their plans. If you are still experiencing an **H14 error**, try to **reconfigure your dyno**. Just change your dyno type to the subscribed plan and make sure you have toggle the selected dyno to the right in order to enable it.

[image]

Comment: This is at least the third time you've given this exact answer. [Please don't do that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/248627).

Comment: What's difference between Eco Dyno and the Basic Dyno?